# What is the definition of "No One" in CIS, and SID choice for Windows systems

Tags: windows

I was reading an CIS (Center for Internet Security) document that is about Windows 10 Enterprise. I have read many pages and some steps states like this

> 2.2.27 (L1) Ensure 'Lock pages in memory' is set to **'No One'**

I could not find any useful information about meaning of **No One**. However, what I found is that Microsoft has a list of SIDs [0] which Null Authority (`S-1-0`) and Nobody (`S-1-0-0`) fit for the definition.

So, what should I do? Just leave the value empty string; use `S-1-0`, or use `S-1-0-0`.

[0]: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems

Comment: I'm pretty sure this statement means only that a system shouldn't assign anyone the [lock pages in memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/lock-pages-in-memory) privilege. It's not literally a "no one" security principal.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @ErykSun. I have looked many InSpec profiles, so many of them uses `""` string.

Comment: We definitely wouldn't assign this privilege to "Nobody" or the null authority.